# Programming The Atmega Chips

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, programming, atmega328p

Can someone explain a little bit to me how to program the Atmega MCU for example the Atmega328P without the arduino??

So, what i want is to program the Atmega chip without Arduino IDE but using the Atmel Studio and a programmer.

When i seaech the internet they said that i need to program the chip with Arduino first.

In order to clarify my question, imagine we live in a world that Arduino isn't exist.The Arduino company, Arduino board, IDE, Arduino bootloader  and all things related to Arduino isn't exist.And in that world i want to program the Atmega328p chip.Without the Arduino bootloader.

Please explain to me what device i need and how to get started doing that?
And last question, if i success doing that, can i use sensor that designed for Arduino (for example HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor) with that chip?

Any comments/answers are appreciated.Thanks

Comment: google "avrisp"

Comment: The answer is the same for any MCU out there: go to product website, buy programmer hardware, download their IDE or dedicated programming software, enjoy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please explain to me what device i need and how to get started doing that?

you will need a few things:

1) you will need an environment within which to develop your code (and produce a .hex file). AVR Studio or Atmel studio would be one of them. I personally use Code::Blocks and IAR;

2) once the code is developed, you will need a programmer to load it onto the chip. Tons of programmers and Atmel makes quite a few of them. You should look into your environment to see what it supports and go from there. I have used a Dragon, but my favorite is a usbasp programmer.

3) your programmer typically needs a piece of software to drive it. obviously, you will need to pick the software that matches your programmer. I use avrdude+avrdudess for that.

that's pretty much all there is to it.

Answer (score 2):

There are several different ways or programming the AVR series chips.  Most require a programmer, but some (AT90USB*, ATmegaU* and similar) can be programmed over USB with no special hardware.  Regardless of which you choose, the process goes like this:

1. Lay out PCB including the connector you'll use for programming
2. Build PCB
3. Build your program using AVR-GCC, Atmel Studio, or whatever toolchain takes your fancy.
4. Plug the programmer into your PC, and into your PCB.  Unless using USB, in which case, just plug your PC streight into the PC.
5. Use Atmel Studio or arvdude to copy your compiled program onto your chip, and optionally also program EEPROM and fuses.

The only tricky bit is making sure you have a programming method which is supported by your chip and your programmer, and then putting the correct connector on the board.
Some example methods:

**ICSP/ISP** Supported by many AVR chips, and most (all?) programmers, usually uses a 2x3 pin header on the board.

**JTAG** Also used for debugging, this tends to appear on larger chips, and normally uses a 10-pin header on the board.

**USB** Only available on chips with hardware USB, doesn't need a programmer at all. Instead the chips come with a bootloader, much like Arduinos.

Comment: So i where i connect that 6-pins on AVRISP mkII?? And where i connect the 328p chip??

Comment: Look in the datasheet for the 328P chip, page 3 tells you which pin is which.  Some pins have several uses, separated by slashes.  You'll need to connect RESET, SCK, MISO, MOSI, Vcc and GND to the 6-pin connector on the PCB you make.

Comment: More preciselly, you need to connect those signals to correct pins somehow. It is possible to connect directly to pins of 328P and do nothing else, like with  patch cables from the programmer (even withoout any PCB), or via any internal connector(s) which contains it, or by pressing wires to the pins directly (probabely you would make some holder for the contacs, but any magic do)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing Arduino really does to simplify the "programming" is providing the bootloader. The bootloader allows you change the contents of the flash memory without using a dedicated programming interface.

Normally you would program the Atmega328p and most other AVR controllers using an interface like JTAG, PDI or ISP. Those are interfaces that follow specific hardware and software implementations. To programm a controller using one of those interface you require a programmer that can interface with those. Common programmers are AVRISP-mk2, AVRDRAGON and JTAGICE for example.

If you connect one of those programmers to the correct pins, you can manipulate EEPROM, FLASH (including the bootloader) and FUSES. Some interfaces even allow in-system debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It is all explained in the Atmel documentation, in the real world the Arduinos are a very small use case for the AVR family.

The documentation shows the various ways to program those parts, which is typical these days for microcontrollers to have multiple choices.  There is the built in bootloader, which at least on older AVRs you could modify yourself.  There is the ISP interface they call it which varies across the family but is pretty easy to bit bang from pretty much anything with a few TTL signals (ftdi device, another microcontroller, raspberry pi, etc), the protocol is documented in other atmel documents.

And there are numerous off the shelf devices and/or free or pay for software that uses one/some of these devices to program these parts using these protocols.

If you want to use the atmel studio and atmel programmer then again you need to just read the documentation on that to see what is supported.

The whole of developing for this type of product is reading the documentation and using what you read.  You are not going to get very far if you dont or wont.